# Why is there a large overhead in pickling numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, pickle

Suppose I have a simple array in Python:

```
>>> x = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
```

When pickled, it is a reasonably small size:

```
>>> pickle.dumps(x).__len__()
44
```

How come if I use a numpy array, the size is so much larger?

```
>>> xn = np.array(x)
>>> pickle.dumps(xn).__len__()
187
```

Converting it to a less precise data type only helps a little bit...

```
>>> x16 = xn.astype('float16')
>>> pickle.dumps(x16).__len__()
163
```

Other numpy/scipy data structures like sparse matrices also don't pickle well.  Why?

Comment: `pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(sparse.coo_matrix(x)))` works fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking it in a debugger, a numpy array has the fields like max, min, type etc apart from the data, which I am not sure a python list has.

A complete list can be found on http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html

As pickling is just a binary copying, these other fields are also being copied, resulting in a larger size.

Comment: The `pickle` of a `ndarray` is essentially a string version of its `np.save`.  That has modest overhead buffer (200 bytes or so) plus a copy of its main data buffer.  The overhead has essential info like `shape` and `dtype`.  The data buffer size depends entirely on the number of elements (and dtype).  It is essentially `x.nbytes` long.