# How does pickle (Python) work with C++ extensions?

Tags: python, c++, numpy, memory, pickle

For example, in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31304006/why-is-there-a-large-overhead-in-pickling-numpy-arrays/31304244), it seems that pickling copies some fields that aren't from the data itself like max / min. However, does this really explain how a C++ structure can be 4 times larger than the python equivalent? For example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pickle as pk
>>> print(len(pk.dumps(np.zeros(10000))))
80159
>>> print(len(pk.dumps([0]*10000)))
20026
>>>
```

There's no way that a single attribute would be that large (ex. max, min, etc.), would it? Also it seems that the general consensus is that a C++ structure is more compact, thus requiring less RAM:

```
class MyClass{
public:
    int i;
    int j;
};
```

would contain just 2 ints, while the python equivalent would have

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__():
        self.i = 0 # PyObject, should be bigger than an int
        self.j = 0
```

How does pickle copy data to make it so much larger?

Thanks

Comment: The array pickle size is reasonable, 10000 elements * 8 bytes per element (only  159 overhead).  `[0]*10000` is a list with 10000 references to the unique `0` object; I don't know how `list` does its pickle.  The actual `pickle` method is class dependent.  While there's a generic `object` pickle, many classes have their method.  The `ndarray` method is essentially the same as its `np.save` function.

Comment: I don't see the connection between your class examples and pickles of a list and `ndarray`.

Comment: I was just trying to say that since the C++ object is smaller than python, shouldn't the pickle object smaller?

Comment: I don't see the pickle of a `c++` object anywhere.

Comment: isn't numpy implemented in C++?

Comment: Also I've tried pickled an array of MyClass and its 10x larger than the python equivalent

Comment: No, `numpy` is mostly `c`.  And its `pickle/save` is essentially a copy of its main data buffer.  You haven't shown anything about how your `c++` class is integrated with Python, or how you are using `pickle` (assuming you are even using the Python pickle).